# Applying Perlin Noise to Tiles

Tags: tiles, data-structure, perlin-noise, heightmap

Playing with some Documentation about Perlin Noise I managed to create this map:

[image]

Nothing different from other Procedural Generated Maps. It is a HeightMap with colours at given heights.

The problem I am having with it is that this Colour Map it's in a single plane.

**QUESTION**

**¿How can I draw the Perlin Noise Map in a plane made by a set of individual tiles?**

The idea behind that question is that each tile will have a set of values such as population, water levels, soil quality, temperature and etc. I want to store things which can not be done on a simple single plane (according to my knowledge in this matter).

**EDIT:**
Ok, after some more planning and research in the matter I did the next thing:

I have created a new class type named MapData.cs, this class will hold information about the heights, temperature, wetness and etc form the map as show below

**MapData class**

```
    public class MapData{

    //The MapData class will hold different types of Data
    //Temperature, Rainfall, etc.

    public float[,] Data;
    public float Min { get; set; }
    public float Max { get; set; }

    public MapData(int width, int height)
    {
        Data = new float[width, height];
        Min = float.MinValue;
        Max = float.MaxValue;
    }


}
```

Then i will use that MapData class to put data into the tiles as show below:

**Load Tiles function inside the Generator Class**

```
void LoadTiles()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++)
        {
            Tiles t = new Tiles();
            t.X = x;
            t.Y = y;

            float heightValue = HeightData.Data[x, y];
            heightValue = (heightValue - HeightData.Min) / (HeightData.Max - HeightData.Min);
            t.HeightValue = heightValue;

            if (heightValue < DeepWater)
            {
                t.HeightValue = DeepWater;
            }
            else if (heightValue < ShallowWater)
            {
                t.HeightValue = ShallowWater;
            }
            else if (heightValue < Sand)
            {
                t.HeightValue = Sand;
            }
            else if (heightValue < Grass)
            {
                t.HeightValue = Grass;
            }
            else if (heightValue < Forest)
            {
                t.HeightValue = Forest;
            }
            else if (heightValue < Mountain)
            {
                t.HeightValue = Mountain;
            }
            else { t.HeightValue = Snow; }
        }
    }
```

My actual problem here is that i am still confused with the Texture Generator as how do i apply this new concept into it. I am still learning and I do not want to mess up my progress.

**Texture Generator**

```
    public class TextureGenerator{

    //Height Colours
    private static Color DeepColor = new Color(15 / 255f, 30 / 255f, 80 / 255f, 1);
    private static Color ShallowColor = new Color(15 / 255f, 40 / 255f, 90 / 255f, 1);
    private static Color RiverColor = new Color(30 / 255f, 120 / 255f, 200 / 255f, 1);
    private static Color SandColor = new Color(198 / 255f, 190 / 255f, 31 / 255f, 1);
    private static Color GrassColor = new Color(50 / 255f, 220 / 255f, 20 / 255f, 1);
    private static Color ForestColor = new Color(16 / 255f, 160 / 255f, 0, 1);
    private static Color RockColor = new Color(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1);
    private static Color SnowColor = new Color(1, 1, 1, 1);



    //This class will receive the colorMap array we set up before along with width and height

    public static Texture2D TextureFromColourMap(Color[] colourMap, int width, int height)
    {
        //New texture object and apply that color code.
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(width, height);
        texture.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;
        texture.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Clamp;
        texture.SetPixels(colourMap);
        texture.Apply();

        return texture;
    }
    
    public static Texture2D TextureFromHeightMap (float[,] heightMap)
    {
        int width = heightMap.GetLength(0);//Grab the x from the heightMap array
        int height = heightMap.GetLength(1);//Grabt the y from the heightMap array

        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(width, height);//New texture object 

        Color[] colourMap = new Color[width * height];//New colourMap object
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                //Gray scale colours for the NoiseMap
                colourMap[y * width + x] = Color.Lerp(Color.black, Color.white, heightMap[x, y]);//Explained before in Noise Script
            }
        }


        return TextureFromColourMap(colourMap, width, height);//Using the gray scale, coloursMap has colours in it!
    }
}
```

I had inside the texture Generator some colour code for my initial tests for coloring the Perlin Noise over a plane. As you can see up in the image.

Comment: Why would addressing a particular tile in your grid need to be fundamentally different from addressing a particular pixel on the texture plane?

Comment: Can a pixel store all that data i mentioned before? Population, rain, soil and everything i want?

Comment: 1) Yes, if you have enough texture channels 2) What I'm saying is if you know how to set something like `MapPixel[x,y] = GenerateTerrainColourAt(x,y)`, can't you use effectively the same principles to set `Tile[x,y].population = GeneratePopulationAt(x,y)` or `PopulationTiles[x,y] = ...`? I'm trying to identify what specific kind of help you need moving from the generation you've done so far to your tile-based approach.

Comment: Because i though that with Tiles i could somewhat divide the map in "Square/Data Regions". When i first read your question i though... omg what if i have 100*100 = 10000 pixels?! That could be handy for precision for meterological data actually, but for now i will go for very basics

Comment: 10000 is not a big number as far as computers are concerned. You shouldn't encounter much difficulty with that. And yes, you can absolutely divide your map into chunks of any shape & configuration you want. Have you encountered a specific problem in making these divisions, that we might be able to help you with?

Comment: The problem i encountered is that how do i cast the perlin noise on individual tiles. For example, i create an array of Tiles[x,y] (a plane) and i want to draw in them the whole map i created. So far i could just do it in one single GameObject (one Tile) as i did with the 2D plane. I also thought about using a grid over that planeMap and manage data there. But i guess i will go with tiles

Comment: If you zoom in that generated map you will see like "squares" how i could turn them into individual tiles(GameObjects)?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still having trouble understanding what problem you're trying to solve. Is it about creating a separate renderable object (like a quad or sprite) for each tile? Or associating properties to each tile in a grid, or applying chunked generation/loading to your map, or something else yet?

Comment: Associating properties to each tile on the map i generated.

Comment: After a day of thinking i understood the next:  1) a pixel can "store" data if i create multiple layers of data that shares the same position [x, y] with the pixel.

Comment: Yes indeed. We do this sometimes for G-buffers in deferred rendering, or when storing ambient, normal, occlusion, and sprcularity/smoothness/roughness maps for an object — each texture or each channel can carry different information about a given point in the 2D surface space. With this in mind, can you edit your question to elaborate on what you need help with to proceed to your next step?

Comment: For now i will try to apply this knowledge and then, if i can not answer it myself, i will edit the question and be more specific. My objective is that if i place an object over that plane it will be affected by the data at pos [x,y]MapData (Temprerature, rain, etc). Do you see now?

Comment: Just wanna mention that your map looks absolutely cool. Color scheme and height anchor points are well balanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EUREKA!**

**Introduction**

My initial question was about **"How to Tiling with Perlin Noise"**

I had in mind creating a plane with tiles (kind of a grid) [width * height] and on those tiles i will paint different textures. (*That was kind of a brain fuck for me*)

Initially i started with a plane and a texture material applied on it. It worked perfectly but i wanted some kind of way/ability to divide the map somehow in squares for purposes out of this question.

The result is the photo at the head of the question.

**How i solved my problem?**

Thanks to DMGregory and his infinite wisdom i started doing research and found out i could create multiple textures and apply them into the plane terrain AND i could access values the same way i access pixels to paint them.

**Solution**

I created a Data[,] container to store the random values generated,

```
MapData HeightData
```

then i "Tilled" them. **How?**

```
public void LoadTiles(MapData HeightData)
```

This load container which will help me display information gathered in the previous container into a texture using:

`public static Texture2D GetHeightMapTexture(int width, int height, Tiles[,] tile)`

And this is the result:

[image]

It is the same height map as i did before but this one code i remade helps me being more organized and it is expandable *(easy to add more code without lose yourself and suffer depression)*